# Windows Phone 8.1 | How to determine if file exists in local folder?

Tags: file, windows-phone-8.1

How to determine if file exists in local folder (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder)
on Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct method for now to check if file exists. You can try to use one of two methods:

- get a file, and if exception is thrown then it means that file doesn't exist,
- list all files and check if there is one with searched filename

A simple extension methods can look like this:

```cs
public static class FileExtensions
{
    public static async Task<bool> FileExists(this StorageFolder folder, string fileName)
    {
        try { StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName); }
        catch { return false; }
        return true;
    }

    public static async Task<bool> FileExist2(this StorageFolder folder, string fileName)
    { return (await folder.GetFilesAsync()).Any(x => x.Name.Equals(fileName)); }
}
```

Then you can use them like this:

```cs
bool isFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.FileExists("myfile.txt");
```

The second method can be little faster in case the file doesn't exist and there are few files in a folder, hence the exception is not being thrown.

Comment: From what I know, the first method suggested by Romasz is the most commonly used. I'd say it's better than the second option as it allows you to check for files in subfolders and is more consistent, although perhaps slower in some cases.