# Access denied to KnownFolders.MusicLibrary

Tags: unit-testing, uwp, win-universal-app

i have declared the capability  `<uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary" />` in my manifest , but i still get exception in my unit test. Im testing the following code :

```
private readonly StorageFolder _files;
public PlaylistAccess(smil smil)
{
    _files = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary; // I'm getting access denied here
}

public  void SavePlaylist()
{
    IAsyncOperation<StorageFile> file;
    try
    {
        var playlistName = GetFavouritePlaylistName();
        if (!File.Exists(KnownFolders.MusicLibrary + @"\" + playlistName))
            file =  _files.CreateFileAsync(playlistName);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // ignored
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Okay if I run the application and debug (instead of test method), I don't get the exception. I guess if I test single unit test, it doesn't get the app manifest into account? How can I use unit tests then ?

Comment: look at the templates available in New Project -> Windows Universal and you will find a template called "Unit Test App". I think this is what you need in order to run your tests.

Comment: @Rafael yea its the one i use , the others wont run anyway.

Comment: I just created a quick one, added the capability through the package manifest view and it is working with no exceptions. make sure u selected the correct capability which is "Music Library"

Comment: Generally in UWP avoid using file paths - in your case `File.Exists` - use StorageFile/Folder instead.

Comment: @Romasz so i get exception why trying to get file which is not existing with storageFolder?

Comment: Not sure how `File.Exists` works, but normally in UWP you check for file existence by accessing it - in this case if you don't have permission, you will get access denied. Try to check [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28486320/2681948) and see if it helps.

Comment: @Romasz you are right , but im checking file only in KnownFolder.Music . Naah , the problem is i only get access denied if i unit test the SavePlaylist method , if i run the application i dont get exception. I guess something to do with unit test doesnt get capabilities from manifest(its uwp unit test)